# Custom error message for loopback 4 model schema validation

Tags: loopback4

In my model, I have defined a model schema. One of the property is the name which is a required field and minimum character should be of length 5.

```
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    jsonSchema: {
      title: 'name',
      minLength: 5,
      maxLength: 64,
    },
  })
  name: string;
```

But the issue is the error message I get if validation for name fails is (i.e. I pass less than 5 characters),

```
{
    "error": {
        "statusCode": 422,
        "name": "UnprocessableEntityError",
        "message": "should NOT be shorter than 5 characters"
    }
}
```

How can I define a custom error message?

Answer (score 4):

I found it in loopback4 documentation that you can define customer error message in jsonSchema object itself. Please find below code,

```
@property({
   name: 'name',
   description: "The product's common name.",
   type: 'string',
   // Specify the JSON validation rules here
   jsonSchema: {
      maxLength: 30,
      minLength: 10,
      errorMessage: 'name must be at least 10 characters and maximum 30 characters',
   },
})
```

Goto https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Model.html#id-properties and search for section,

> Validation Rules

You will get this property to set custom error message. I checked and its working fine!

Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks For the comment. Did not really work for me but I will try updating my @loopback/rest module and try again.

Answer (score 0):

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

I am able to reproduce your scenario using LoopBack's [Todo example app](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/examples/todo). Here is the full error response I am seeing:

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 422,
    "name": "UnprocessableEntityError",
    "message": "The request body is invalid. See error object `details` property for more info.",
    "code": "VALIDATION_FAILED",
    "details": [
      {
        "path": "/name",
        "code": "minLength",
        "message": "should NOT be shorter than 5 characters",
        "info": {
          "limit": 5
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `details` field contains machine-readable information that can be used by clients to render a human-friendly error message:

- The `path` field is pointing to the (deep) property that did not pass validation (`name`).
- The `code` field contains the validation rule that was violated (`minLength`).
- `info.limit` provides additional information about the validation rule.

The error message you posted does not look familiar to me. Did you configure a custom error handler in your application (see [Handling errors in Sequence](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Sequence.html#handling-errors))? Are you perhaps using an older version of `@loopback/rest`? Can you please update your LoopBack dependencies to their latest versions and see if you get more helpful error messages?

Comment: Yes, I have indeed configured a custom error handler. That's why there are no details in my response.

Comment: I am using version 1.5.1 of loopback/rest module.

Answer (score 0):

To customize the error message, there's a section in https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Validation-REST-layer.html#customize-validation-errors related to this.

You can also see a running app in: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/examples/validation-app/src/sequence.ts.